# How to call progress bar defined in wcf service - c#

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, tcpclient

I have a client(WinForms Application)/Server (WCF Service) where I am doing some complex logic which writes packets to a remote host - this process takes about 20 minutes to write to a specific point but does not complete. So I want to show progress and attempt to continue from where I last stopped in my client application in the form of a progress bar.

```
  //Service:
  public class ServiceImplementation: IServiceInterface{
    ProgressBar pgBar = new ProgressBar();

  public void complexFunction(byte[] data_to_send, UInt32 start_addr){
     pgBar.Maximum = data_to_send.Length;
     for(int i = 0; i < data_to_send.Length; i += 64){
      //do some logic
     }
      pgBar.Value = i;
   }
 }

 //Client
  private void btnProgComplexFunction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
     callComplexFunction
  }

  void callComplexFunction(){
     ServiceImplementation.ServiceImplementationClient proxyInstance = new 
    ServiceImplementation.ServiceImplementationClient();

    //I attempted doing the following but obviously it doesn't work because progress bar returns an integer (e.g pgBar.Value = 100;). The problem lies here. I have been cracking my skull for two days straight
    pgBar.Value = proxyInstance.complexFunction(data_to_send, start_addr);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to async call to your web service. Also need to soap client to this. You can achive it with download progress feature to do this.

You can check this article.

http://shenoyatwork.blogspot.com.tr/2006/10/showing-download-progress-with-net.html

Comment: Why would I need a soap message? I had a look at that article and I don't get what's going on because everything is just clustered. Could you break it down to me into a skeletal structure in the same manner as how I posed my question?